# .htaccess - Help me understand the behavior

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I use xampp on my local PC. The .htaccess file is placed in the `/test/` folder. I am testing the address **`localhost/test`** on chrome browser.

The .htaccess file is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . http://google.com
```

This redirects to Google. The same as this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .. http://google.com
```

The same with 3 dots, 4 dots, 5 dots, 6 dots, 7 dots, 8 dots, 9 dots.

But when there are 10 dots or more redirection does not work. So this does not do redirection (10 dots)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .......... http://google.com
```

What do the dots actually mean in such a .htaccess file? Are they a regex? What is that magic number of 10?

**edit**
I probably found out the reason. The file that is opened on the addresse of `localhost/test` is `index.php`. This file name length is actually 9 letters.

So nine or less dots match it but 10 dots do not. I think this is the answear.

**edit2**
There is still something magic in the dots. Now I have put the .htaccess file to the empty directory of `test2` and have started to test the address of `localhost/test2`.

The redirection takes place up to 13 dots. For 14 dots and more there is no redirection. Confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the answear in apache error log file. This regex pattern of dots is matched against some default file names even if there is only .htaccess file in the directory. In my configuration that default file names are:

```
index.php
index.pl
index.cgi
index.asp
index.shtml
index.html
index.htm
default.php
default.pl
default.cgi
default.asp
default.shtml
```

The matching ends at `default.shtml` file name that has just 13 letters (as 13 dots). Actually that `default.shtml` file is not present in the directory. Then redirection starts.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with a standard PCRE. The dots are not magic, each one means 'match any character'. It must be matching 13 characters in the path component (everything after the current directory's trailing slash) for the google redirect, but not 14. To see what it's actually matching, Try replacing it with this rule:

```
RewriteRule .+ https://www.google.com/search?q=$0 [B,L,R]
```

Do you have a previous rule that is missing the `L` flag, which tells the engine to stop looking for matches?

Comment: I have just found the answear in apache error log file. This regex pattern of dots is matched against some default file names: index.php, index.pl, index.cgi, index.asp etc. even if there is only the .htaccess in the directory. When one of that file name has 13 characters the redirection starts. Thank you for the answear.

Comment: I like your way to see what it's actually matching but in fact my answear is the only good answear. Thanks anyway and the point.

Comment: Okay mate, whatever you reckon. You may want to add the `NS` flag to your rules.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apache documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

The syntax of a `RewriteRule` is `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]`, where `Pattern` is a "perl compatible regular expression." This would explain the behaviour you have observed!